# How can I automatically split a list up based on a given requirement?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

On Discord, you can only have messages of character length 2000 or under. I am trying to append the server name, member amount and server ID for each server that the bot is in to a list, and then sending the list to a channel.

However, as the list length exceeds 2000 I have tried to split it up, however the method requires it to be updated every time manually as the list gets larger. How can I make the script automatically split up the list based on how many 'splits' are required and then send those 'splits'?

What I have so far, which works, but is not automatic:

```
@commands.command()
async def getallservers(self, ctx):
    serverslist = []

    def split_list(alist, wanted_parts=1):
        length = len(alist)
        return [ alist[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts] 
                for i in range(wanted_parts) ]

    if ctx.author.id == 204616460797083648:
        for x in self.bot.guilds:
            serverslist.append(f'{x.name}: **{len(x.members)}** - {x.id}\n')

        q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6 = split_list(serverslist, wanted_parts=6)

        embed = discord.Embed(title='Server List')

        embed.description = ''.join(q1)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        embed.description = ''.join(q2)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        embed.description = ''.join(q3)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        embed.description = ''.join(q4)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        embed.description = ''.join(q5)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        embed.description = ''.join(q6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Not directly related, but you should use library's builtin checks instead of a `if owner: ... else: pass` inside the command.

Comment: Yep - this was just a temporary thing that I added for testing the command - will definitely change it over! Thank you!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

One you have the `serverslist`, you can pass it to a function that builds < 2000 character pages

```
def paginate(lines, chars=2000):
    size = 0
    message = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) + size > chars:
            yield message
            message = []
            size = 0
        message.append(line)
        size += len(line)
    yield message
```

then in your command

```
for message in paginate(serverlist):
    embed.description = ''.join(message)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!